# Update Account object fields based on contact record using process builder

Tags: process-builder, process

Process builder is not getting triggered when m trying to update an account picklist values based on creation of contact object. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: did you create process on Account? Did you activate your process?

Comment: No, I have created process on Contact and i've activated it and i've also tried creating on Account .but it is still not working.

Comment: looks like you want to trigger process every time contact is created? if so you need to query related account and update pick list field. but are you sure that you've set accountId up in contact record?

Comment: Yes and ya i've set accountId in contact record as well..Dont know what's the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the details of the relevant steps in your process builder and the details of the fields you are using as criteria.

Comment: welcome to SFSE; please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community